# CSS angled border extra pixel when zoomed

Tags: css, sass

I'm using the `:after` selector to create an angled border on a div. It looks fine until you zoom in to 125% or 175%, at which point there's an missing pixel in the angled portion. From what I've read this is caused by browsers not being able to round the pixel width accurately.

Any idea how I can get these to line up with just CSS/SCSS? Thanks

*100% looks good*

[image: Image zoom 100%]

*125% misaligned borders*

[image: Image zoom 125%]

https://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/qqywvynx/

```
<div class="flag">Tester</div>

    .flag {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color: #ff8a00;
        line-height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 8px;
        margin-right: 20px;    

        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
            padding-right: 4px;
            border-color: #ff8a00 transparent #ff8a00 #ff8a00;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `.em` for `border-width`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I tried `.em` but had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my solution the trick is to split them up and let them overlap. have fun :)

```
.flag {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #ff8a00;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin-right: 20px;    
    position: relative;
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        right: -13px;
        bottom: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 10px 11px 0;
        padding-right: 5px;
        border-color: #ff8a00 transparent #ff8a00 #ff8a00;
    }
    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        right: -13px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 11px 10px 0 0;
        padding-right: 5px;
        border-color: #ff8a00 transparent #ff8a00 #ff8a00;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it thanks! The only minor change I made was some `padding-right` on the parent element so the text wasn't cut off.

Comment: Here's my slightly modified version of @Rudi's. Thanks again https://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/qqywvynx/2/